# C++: Adding and redefinition of default arguments in real world

Tags: c++, language-features, default-arguments

There is a possibility to add or redefine default arguments of a function in C++. Let's look at the example:

```
void foo(int a, int b, int c = -1) {
    std::cout << "foo(" << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << ")\n";
}

int main() {
    foo(1, 2);   // output: foo(1, 2, -1)

    // void foo(int a, int b = 0, int c);
    // error: does not use default from surrounding scope

    void foo(int a, int b, int c = 30);
    foo(1, 2);   // output: foo(1, 2, 30) 

    // void foo(int a, int b, int c = 35);
    // error: we cannot redefine the argument in the same scope

    // has a default argument for c from a previous declaration
    void foo(int a, int b = 20, int c);
    foo(1);      // output: foo(1, 20, 30)

    void foo(int a = 10, int b, int c);
    foo();       // output: foo(10, 20, 30)

    {
        // in inner scopes we can completely redefine them
        void foo(int a, int b = 4, int c = 8);
        foo(2);  // output: foo(2, 4, 8)
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Online version to play with: http://ideone.com/vdfs3t

These possibilities are regulated by the standard in 8.3.6. More specific details are in 8.3.6/4

> For non-template functions, default arguments can be added in later
>   declarations of a function in the same scope. Declarations in
>   different scopes have completely distinct sets of default arguments.
>   That is, declarations in inner scopes do not acquire default arguments
>   from declarations in outer scopes, and vice versa. In a given function
>   declaration, each parameter subsequent to a parameter with a default
>   argument shall have a default argument supplied in this or a previous
>   declaration or shall be a function parameter pack. A default argument
>   shall not be redefined by a later declaration (not even to the same
>   value)
>   ...

To tell the truth I never use this feature when coding in c++. I used similar code snippets several times to surprise my colleagues, but certainly not in the production code. Thus, the question is: Do you know real world examples of the code that use these features with benefits?

Comment: Sometimes it's really difficult to love `C++` ... sigh...

Comment: interesting. Unpredictable behavior of c++. At least it doesn't allow re-declaring in the same scope(e.g. just above main). Also it didn't allow within scope of same class.

Comment: IIUC this is present since 1980s. I personally consider it as a legacy feature.

Comment: @cpplearner Anyway I cannot see any other use but for the fact that it can save me from typing in the same values in a function from within a context when I invoke it several times. Have you any other real world example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot change some existing code or library and you really cannot be bothered to type the correct argument then changing the default argument for some scope could be a solution.

It seems like the kind of hack that could be useful when working with C++ code generated by some legacy tool. For example, if the generated code has always had hundreds calls into some external library using a default argument but now the default argument is no longer correct.