# Function definition with initialized arguments and Function call with less arguments

Tags: c++, default-arguments

I came across with a confusing question during an examination. Please help me to understand this concept. Code snippet is including here :

```
void xyz(int a = 0, int b, int c = 0)
{
    cout << a << b << c;
}
```

Now the question is which of the following calls are illegal?

*(Assume h and g are declared as integers)*

```
(a) xyz();    (b) xyz(h,h);

(c) xyz(h);    (d) xyz(g,g);
```

**Codes:**

**(1)** (a) and (c) are correct     **(2)** (b) and (d) are correct

**(3)** (a) and (b) are correct     **(4)** (b) and (c) are correct

**I tried to compile the code in C++ and I got this error:**

> error:expected ';',',' or ')' before '=' token
>   void xyz (int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0)

Help me understand the concept.

Comment: Is this C or C++? Default arguments. And `a` can't have a default argument if `b` (and `c`) doesn't have one. That's your error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default value of function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842928/default-value-of-function-parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put default assignment in right.

```
void xyz(int a , int b= 0, int c = 0)
{
    count <<a<<b<<c;
}
```

call it like this:

```
xyz(2,3); 
xyz(2,3,5);
```

Answer (score 10):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments):

> In a function declaration, **after a parameter with a default argument,
>   all subsequent parameters must** :
>
> - have a default argument supplied in this or a previous declaration; or
> - be a function parameter pack.

Means

```
void xyz(int a = 0, int b, int c = 0) // Not valid
{
   //your code
}
```

It is give an error because `a` has default value, but `b` after it 
 doesn't have default value. The ordered of function declarations with default argument must be from **right to left**.

So, use

```
void xyz(int a = 0, int b=0, int c = 0) // Not valid
{
   //your code
}
```

Let's see some c++ example:

**case 1:** **Valid**, trailing defaults

```
void xyz(int a, int b = 2, int c = 3)
{
   //your code
}
```

**case 2:** **Invalid**, leading defaults

```
void xyz(int a = 1, int b = 2, int c)
{
      //Your code
}
```

**case 3:** **Invalid**, default in middle

```
void xyz(int a, int b = 3, int c);  
{
      //Your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let's say all arguments are initialized, is it possible to call the function as mentioned in the options.. eg: xyz(h,h)

Comment: It may be worth mentioning the case where such a declaration is valid if preceded by another declaration that already sets the default value for `b`.

Comment: `void xyz(int a, int b = 0, int c = 0);` and then `void xyz(int a = 0, int b, int c);` is a valid use case, missing in the answer.

Comment: @CinCout That's right, but `xyz(int a = 0, int b, int c = 0)` is not valid

Comment: Definitely. But the missing use case makes the answer incomplete IMO.

Comment: @rsp, all of your latter examples can be valid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818513/c-adding-and-redefinition-of-default-arguments-in-real-world

Comment: @DAle If I use individually function in my program, it's give an error. But, If I use all above function in my program then it is valid.Here, OP asked only about single function.

Comment: @rsp, Maybe it would be better to use function definitions (as in the question), not declarations?

Comment: @DAle i did some modification. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's wrong definition of the function.

```
void xyz(int b, int a = 0,  int c = 0)
```

or

```
void xyz(int a = 0, int b = 0,  int c = 0)
```

could be ok.